# AZURE Cloud integration

Tags: c, azure, azure-iot-sdk

I am working on the Azure iot cloud integration, i successfully build my SDK, i am trying compiling with my application, it is giving dependency errors and getting error like given below,

```
 ../../inc/azure_c_shared_utility/crt_abstractions.h:58:23: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
 typedef unsigned char _Bool;
                       
../../inc/azure_c_shared_utility/crt_abstractions.h:58:1: warning: useless type name in empty declaration [enabled by default]
 typedef unsigned char _Bool;
 
../../inc/azure_c_shared_utility/crt_abstractions.h:125:2: error: #error unknown (or C89) compiler, provide ISNAN with the same meaning as isnan in C99 standard
 #error unknown (or C89) compiler, provide ISNAN with the same meaning as isnan in C99 standard
```

Comment: Related Thread:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/186046/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you still blocked?

Try adding these lines to your Makefile to see if it works:

```
 -DCMAKE_C_STANDARD=## \
 -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=## \
```

where ## are the standards for C and C++ (for example, -DCMAKE_C_STANDARD=99 will make the program be compiled against C99 standards).

Please see similar issue addressed [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/1037) for reference.